# I want to draw a line chart in vb.net and do calculations based on that graph

Tags: vb.net

I want to draw a line chart in vb.net 2013, something like shown in the picture:

[image: curve with lines]

I managed to draw a tangent but I am unable to draw the parallel lines.

Comment: It depends on which technology you would like to use. WPF, winform, asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this what you need, but you only need to construct new points at (0.1, 0) and (0.2, 0) and use slope factor of tangent line to get points where you need to draw parallel lines.

```
    Dim A = New Point(120, 80)
    Dim k As Double = 0.5

    Dim kx = 1.0
    Dim ky = kx * k

    Dim A1 = New Point(A.X + kx * 30, A.Y - ky * 30)

    ' Line at 0.1
    Dim B = New Point(110, 100)
    Dim B1 = New Point(B.X + kx * 30, B.Y - ky * 30)

    ' Line at 0.2
    Dim C = New Point(120, 100)
    Dim C1 = New Point(C.X + kx * 30, C.Y - ky * 30)
```

Comment: My curve comes form the database and its plotted by the function  "Me.SS.Series(0).Points.AddXY(xPt, yPt)" where xPt and yPt comes from the database.  now the tangent is also plotted by the database files by marking 10 % and 60 % of the max value. also my 0.1 and 0.2 lines have fixed x1 and y1 values but i unable to calculate the x2 and y2 values for plotting my lines

Comment: So you have tangent start point and end point, then you can use above sample, you need to calculate k as (y2-y1)/ (x2-x1)  where x1,y1, and x2,y2 are starting and ending point of tangent line.

Comment: I calculated the value k as you stated. my first point if 0.1 and 0.2 lines have values as (0.1,0) and (0.2,0) respectively but my ending points are not fixed so what to do about that

Comment: It depends, like in above sample you can use predefined length (30 in above case), or you can use length of the tangent line, then just calculate ending point as y2 = y1 + ky * length and x2 = x1 + kx * length.